# Why Is My Github Pages Custom Domain Constantly Reset?

Tags: github, web-deployment, github-pages

I go into the page in Github (https://github.com/user/repo/settings/pages) and set a custom domain. It works great!

However, every time I deploy (using the gh-pages npm package) it resets the domain back to

```
 https://user.github.io/repo
```

This is incredibly frustrating... how can I tell it to use my custom domain permanently?

Answer (score 13):

It looks like there are reports about this in the repo for `gh-pages` npm package. See [#347](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/347), [#236](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/236), [#370](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/370), [#213](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/213).

There is even a [<strike>still opened</strike> **merged** pull-request](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/pull/375/commits/1e38a134d29b6c8104e74fdb6a4fb5201f65f49c) that tackles the issue through documentation.

Basically, it says:

> Modify the deployment line to your deploy script if you use custom domain. This will prevent deployment to remove the domain from settings in github.
>
> ```
> echo 'your_cutom_domain.online' > ./build/CNAME && gh-pages -d build"
> ```

---

**Edit:** there are other options as well, some people directly change their deployment call and add a custom domain to their deployment scritpt:

```js
var ghpages = require('gh-pages');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('dist/CNAME', "your-custom-domain.com", function(err) {});
ghpages.publish('dist', function(err) {});
```

others just follow the advice for putting `CNAME` to your publishing folder.

Comment: I got confused with the quotation mark around the domain name. Actually, it was not required.

Comment: "deploy": "echo domain.com > ./build/CNAME && gh-pages -d build"

Answer (score 3):

For my React static site I have to add below scripts to the `package.json` to add the `CNAME` file with the custom domain to the `build/` dir before each deployment.

```json
"scripts": {
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "add-domain": "echo \"myAwesomeDomain.org\" > build/CNAME",
   "deploy": "npm run add-domain && gh-pages -d build",
   "bd": "npm run build && npm run deploy",
},
```

Comment: I had to remove the quotes around my domain name for this to work correctly for me.  Thanks for the scripts though. They were quite helpful

Answer (score 2):

For those of you using the GitHub Action [crazy-max/ghaction-github-pages](https://github.com/crazy-max/ghaction-github-pages) there is a setting called `fqdn` that you're looking for. Set that with the custom domain and it stop breaking every deploy.

[See documentation here.](https://github.com/crazy-max/ghaction-github-pages#inputs)

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and the action I use - peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3 - has an analogous `cname` setting.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem for a gatsby site, I needed to install the gatsby-plugin-cname package and add the following to the gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: 'http://custom-domain.com/'
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-cname'
  ],
}
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-cname/

Answer (score -1):

If you are using "npm run deploy" or any npm deployment scripts
Add a CNAME.txt file in public your Directory
In the 1st line enter your custom domain name in it. e.g. (acbd.com)

else
Create and Add the same in you static Directory

Deploy and check